# Laravel 5.2 built-in authorization customization

Tags: php, authorization, customization, laravel-5

SO community!

I have a project, that I've built on Laravel 5.2. As its authorization I am using the built in one, that can be generated by running

```
php artisan make:auth
```

It serves well, but the system's users will be mostly invited by the administrator, whose account is created by the built-in auth action under the route /register. There will be multiple instances of my project hosted separately.
Once the system is set up I do need the route to create the administrator account, but after that I would like the route to be not be accessible.

The customization I need is as follows:
I am thinking about an "if" that would check how many administrator accounts there currently are. If there is at least one, the /register route would redirect to /login.
Something like this:

```
$administrators = User::where( 'role', User::ROLE_ADMIN )->get();
if ( count( $administrators ) != 0 ) return redirect( url('/login') );
```

It is a simple piece of code, but I do not know where to put it.
First possible solution:
At first I was thinking that I would need to customize the register action by adding the check to it, but the AuthController does not have register action and I do not understand how the AuthController works.

Second possible solution:
I was thinking of creating a middleware with the admin count check for the /register route, but in the routes file the built-in authorization routes are somehow condensed and added with this piece of code:

```
Route::auth();
```

Is there some way of extracting the /register route out of that, so I bind the middleware on to it?

Or maybe there is a better way of adding the check.
Any help will be much appreciated!